# Efficient merging of 2.1 billion records on datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several data sets consisting of 2 columns: `ID` and `ActivityDate`. Within an dataset a `ID+ActivityDate` is unique. Each dataset is about 35 million records long. There are 60+ datasets.

My desired out put is basically `ID`, `FirstActivityDate` and `LastActivityDate`. This is basically the reduce part of a map/reduce job.

My first try was basically read the first dataset, establishing the base line, and then as I read the next dataset I do a foreach comparing and updating the `LastActivityDate`. Although the memory used was very acceptable (spiking at 2 GB but consistently under 1.25 GB), this took too long. I made the calculation, the result set should be around 1.5 GB long, so it's local-memory manageable.

```
for x in files:
    parsedData = parseFile(x)
    dt = parsedData[0]
    cards = parsedData[1]
    for card in cards:
        #num = int(card[:16])
        if card in result:
            result[card].lastRecharged = dt
        else:
            result[card]=CreditCard(dt)
```

Commenting that line `#num = int(card[:16])` made the loop execution drop to 30 seconds per file (original was around 150 seconds), but now the memory is out of control. The file parsing is basically a file read, which takes less then 1 second.

My second try was using pandas, but I couldn't merge the datasets the way I want. I must say I'm not proficient in pandas.

Is there a third option?

Comment: Use a database? Change the "map" part of the map/reduce job to avoid needing to merge such amounts of data?

Comment: Not really an option... I don't have a database at hand and the I bet that the sheer IO cost of the select and updates queries would worsen the situation...

Comment: And I bet that many engineers writing and optimizing database code were able to implement such things more efficiently than a Python program can be.

Comment: But anyway, it was only a suggestion, you may have reasons not to use a database.

Comment: Is every dataset guaranteed to have every ID, or is it possible an ID first shows up in some dataset in the middle?

Comment: "I don't have a database at hand" – You always have SQLite at hand with Python!

Comment: Can you show the code of your first try that took too long? (Also, how long was too long and how long would be fast enough?)

Comment: @totalhack it's possible the new IDs pop-up along the way, the same way some might vanish

Comment: What's preventing you from installing mysql, Postgres, etc or Docker to get a local database?

Comment: @Ry- unfortunately not, once it took too long I started to fiddle with it and now it's unrecognisable and does not compile yet... im exploring a way to parallelise the operations. It took about 50sec for the first round (baseline and first "merge"). I was hoping for something like 5sec per round

Comment: @cricket_007 corporate security policies

Comment: Maybe you have enough undo history for a quick copy and paste? :P  In addition to the questions about time: are the inputs sorted or anything?

Comment: OK, that eliminates what I was going to suggest. Seeing the code for your first try would be helpful, it sounds like based on your "foreach" comment that you are looping over the entire dataset in an effort to search for a match. If that's the case, changing the data structure you are searching to be a dict with ID as the key instead will give you O(1) access to the IDs you have seen already.

Comment: A naive script (using `min_by_id`/`max_by_id` dicts) I just wrote reads, compares, and writes out 10,000,000 records (7 million unique IDs) across 10 files in 27 seconds (so 2.7 sec per 1,000,000 entries) on my Mac. That extrapolates to about 1.6 hours, which doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: Okay, so you cannot download anything? Or just not install anything? Do you know how to use `awk`? Can you update the question with any of your code or psuedocode?

Comment: @Ry- check out the edit 2!  
->cricket_007 I rather not do both because I don't like to push rules and check the edit2 also   
->AKX this needs to happen on the fly... the end user will be able to edit data and needs to visualize the outcome, so I guess he will not be happy to w8 that long for it...

Comment: What format is the file in?

Comment: @Ry- both the input and the output are `csv` in the format `{ID},{firstAppearance},{lastAppearance}`... the input does not contain the `{lastAppearance}` though

Comment: You should really look into using `Git` more often to avoid completely throwing away good working code(the first code you wrote) and you should also look into using `threads`(it's definitely I/O) to cut down on the time since you don't want to use a database(note that sqlite is always available).

Comment: @Leonardo "this needs to happen on the fly... the end user will be able to edit data and needs to visualize the outcome, so I guess he will not be happy to w8 that long for it... " What do you mean? Will they be editing those 35-million-row CSVs?

Comment: @AKX sorry for the delay, its carnival here in BR. Not precisely "editing". He will be able to remove and/or insert CSVs. This way he will evaluate the result and decide. so he wont edit individual lines but rather change a whole CSV

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting pretty close to my objective.

Fist I made the reading and parsing into memory concurrent and in batches using `multithreading.pool`, each result was pushed into a queue. Each pool would have 3 consecutive files, cycling in 4 `pools`. In a 5th pool, I pre-merge the dictionaries dropping non-recurrent keys (cards). Then in a 6th pool I do the final merge.

The whole process takes about 75 seconds on my local machine. The whole thing ends up consuming over 4gb of ram, which is not ideal, but manageable.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you are interested on the first and the last `ActivityDate` per each `ID`
If this is the case you could use [dask](https://dask.org/). Let assume all your file are csv and they are stored inside a folder called `data`.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = dd.read_csv("data/*.csv")

# convert ActivityDate to datetime
df["ActivityDate"] = df["ActivityDate"].astype("M8[us]")

# use aggregate
out = df.groupby("ID")\
        .agg({"ActivityDate":["min", "max"]})\
        .compute()

out.columns = ["_".join(col) for col in out.columns]
out = out.reset_index()
out = out.rename(columns={'ActivityDate_min':"FirstActivityDate",
                          'ActivityDate_max':"LastActivityDate"})
```